# How to init a tasklet after a keystroke interrupt?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I would like to build a kernel module, which will run a tasklet when there is a keystroke of `f5` key.

I understand how to init a tasklet, but how do I get the event in my module? How do I use `request_irq` to figure out if `f5` was pressed?

Comment: Do you have to use request_irq?

Wouldn't register_keyboard_notifier be more useful?

Answer (score 1):

-

Hi, 0x90,

I guess you know, to handle a interrupt, there are two parts.
First part, top half, that is interrupt handler,
Second part, bottom half, may be softirq, tasklet, work queue.

So, even if you want to implement all you want in a tasklet, you must make sure the top half, the interrupt handler, has chance to run first.

IIRC, the tasklet is just a variant of softirqs, and they are handled in irq_exit(), which is called in do_IRQ(). But, this flow may depend on the specific archtecture.

For your question, I guess it may be on x86 platform.
Whatever key is pressed, there will always be a keyboard interrupt passed to CPU.
And whether the key pressed is f5, will be checked in your tasklet, your interrupt handler may just need to pass the code to tasklet.

So, you should attach your interrupt handler, which is handled before the tasklet, to the keyboard interrupt by calling request_irq().

Update:

As Probie said,  you may want to check notifier.txt and notifiers.txt in Documentation/ directory.

Thanks.